# Which page is served by Liferay for a friendlyURL for a user?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

When a new user is created in Liferay (6) a group object with a "friendlyUrl" consisting of the screen name of the user is created.

If a user now navigates to that URL, a page is served by Liferay which shows some user data, e.g. first name and last name. In order to prevent this from happening we would like to "hide" this page or make it inaccessible.
However, we were not able to figure out which page this is and how we could achieve this.

Any kind soul could enlighten us?

Comment: I'm voting to close, as this is not programming related (see [help/on-topic]), but rather a software configuration question. However, look at [these options](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Default%20User%20Private%20Layouts) to prevent future personal sites being created (look at the public and private versions)

Comment: well, it is debatable if it is config or programming. A lot the stuff from Liferay can be overwritten by your own code, if you know where and how. So I'm not so sure about this... but thanks for your link I will have a look at it, hadn't found it yet.

Comment: Sure, but then it takes some initial code or tries for stackoverflow (see [ask]). No hard feelings, just pointing out the self-chosen focus on stackoverflow.com - if you bring such questions over to https://liferay.dev/, they're on topic there.